# Why doesn’t 'rm -rf / --no-preserve-root' delete itself and crash?

Tags: rm

```
rm -rf / --no-preserve-root
```

This command will remove everything in my disk. But if it removes everything (including the OS), how can the kernel and current processes keep running?

Comment: it removes disk content while OS remains running in RAM

Comment: Actually, it doesn't remove the content from disk.  It is more complicated than that.  See my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, it is not clear that it *would* succeed in removing everything from the your file system.  (And certainly, most of the data will still be on disk, and you could get it back if you could run a file recovery tool over the disk / disk image.)

But the reason things still work is that the `rm` command is actually using a syscall called `unlink` to remove files.  That syscall will only actually delete a file if the following are true:

1. There are no other (hard) links to the file in the file system.
2. Nothing is using it.  In this context, "using it" could be reading / writing via a file descriptor ... or executing it.

When you run `rm` like that, it won't actually be able to physically delete the OS kernel, the `rm` executable, the executable for your shell and various system daemons, and many other things that are "in use".  Many of these files would be deleted if you were able to cleanly shut down the OS ... but that won't be possible because you have deleted all of the shutdown scripts.

But it is highly likely that you will end up with a system that won't boot properly any more.

Answer (score 2):

1. On most UNIX systems, files that are currently open don't get deleted even if they are removed from the file system (until they are closed).
2. Programs that are already loaded into memory (such as the running kernel and `rm` binary) and don't need to access any more files won't be affected by deleting files.

Answer (score 0):

hahahhahh -- Did you do it yet?

The OS n'stuff runs in ram.  So this probably won't complete.  But it will damage your OS beyond repair.  I can't say I have ever tried it.

If the "rm" binary (for example) is loaded in ram. Then the binary is deleted off disk, there is no reason for the kernel/OS to write the image back to disk - it will be gone.

I have a centos machine I can scrap if anybody wants to see what happens?

Comment: Seriously, many people have dozens of virtual machines at hand, just to try stuff out -- nothing as fascinating as making things not work anymore :)

Comment: Chokes on some of the /dev/ things. cant remove /proc/* things but its trying.  Box is acting up at /var/tmp

Comment: Choked at /var/tmp.  After a few minutes it gave me back the prompt.  Now I try to re-run the command and rm can't be found.  Now for the reboot,  actually shutdown is gone also (silly me).  Boots to rescue mode and I am out of my depth